# Java- Generic Type not found?

Tags: java, generics, interface

i'm writing code for homework and I'm getting this error

```
GenericSet.java:101: error: method map in class GenericSet<T> cannot be applied
to given types;
            E ans = map(item);
                    ^
  required: LMap<T,E>
  found: T
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
    (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to LMap<T,E>)
  where T,E are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in class GenericSet
    E extends Object declared in method <E>map(LMap<T,E>)
Note: GenericSet.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

from what I understand, the interface I'm being given passes in a function, and I have to use the a generic input(T) to get a generic output (E) which will be stored in a new custom generic object that I made. It looks like it's finding T fine but not E. Could you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public <E> ExtendedSet<E> map(LMap<T, E> map) {
        GenericSet<E> finalVal = new GenericSet();
        for (T item: this.myList) {
            E ans = map(item);
            finalVal.addThis(ans);
        }
        return finalVal;
    }
```

Note: the object GenericSet implements ExtendedSet
Note2: The interface method im given to implement looks like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface LMap<T, E> {
    /**
      *Maps an element of type T to type E
      *@param element the source element to map from
      *@return E the destination element to map to
      */
    E map(T element);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to pass an instance of `T` (`item`) to a method that accepts an instance of `LMap<T, E>`. Look at your error more closely: `required: LMap<T,E> :: found: T`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use

```
E ans = map.map(item);
```

A functional interface's method still needs to be invoked via the instance.  By omitting the instance, you're calling `this.map(item)`, which takes an `LMap<T, E>`.

Comment: so is map an object that contains the method map?

Comment: @Josephhooper: Exactly. It's an *implementation* of `LMap<T, E>`, just like any other interface.

Comment: @Josephhooper Don't forget to mark this answer as "accepted answer" by clicking on the checkmark next to the voting arrows! :)